# Test on a physical IOS device with free developer account?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

After a long windy road, installing visual studio for mac on my mac to test an xamarin.forms app on IOS, I ran into the road block that VS2019 for mac would not work with a free developer account.
I then got vs2019 for windows connected to the mac remotely and ran into the same problem.

Since none of the various guides to setting this up actually mentioned you needed the payed 99$ account just to test an app on your local device, I am still not sure if this can or cannot be done.

Is there no way to test my xamarin.forms app on a physical IOS device for free? Obviously I will have to get such an account eventually, but in the testing phase here and now, I would rather not.

Comment: Apple addresses this [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).  Short answer - you should be able to deploy to a local device using a free account.

Comment: They say on-device testing, but I seem to find that that is not for xamarin through visual studio, but only when using xcode direct.

Comment: Microsoft has docs on this process - have you read them?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos

Comment: I wanted to snap back that "of course i have!", but upon closer inspection I seem to have missed the distinction between provisioning and free provisioning, and though I certainly did read that link, there seem to be something I have to go back and read more carefully now.
Thanks for reminding me about that... and sorry for almost snapping at you, after a very very long day :-)